# Javascript Dot Notation vs Bracket Notation

Tags: javascript, brackets, notation

I am trying to figure out why console prints `undefined` when I use `dot notation` when why it prints values of each key when I use `bracket notation`.

What I want is to print the values of each key, so I use bracket notation. I just want to know why dot notation doesn't work.

Below is the example.

```
const sunny = { mac: 'priest', dennis: 'calculating', charlie: 'birdlaw', dee: 'bird', frank: 'warthog' };

for(var key in sunny){
  console.log(sunny.key)
}

for(var key in sunny){
  console.log(sunny[key])
}
```

> undefined
>   undefined
>   undefined
>   undefined
>   undefined
>   "priest"
>   "calculating"
>   "birdlaw"
>   "bird"
>   "warthog"

Comment: `sunny.key` is looking for the attribute `key` itself, not it's value.

Comment: You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects for reference, specifically the **Objects and properties** section

Comment: @AdamAzad Hi Adam, I am really new to JavaScript. Could you explain why key is the index? I thought for...in statements iterates enumerable **properties**

Comment: It has nothing to do with the for in loop, it has to do with how dot notation works.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var key in sunny){
  console.log(sunny.key)
}
```

sunny.key in bracket notation is equivalent to sunny["key"]. It is searching for a property name "key" which is not there in your object.Hence returning undefined always.

key here is actually variable , not a string to extract the value of a property.

See : https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781

Answer (score 1):

When you write `sunny.key` you are accessing the property/field called `key` on the instance `sunny`; NOTE, this has absolutely nothing to do with the variable called `key`. `sunny.key` in your example is equivalent to `sunny["key"]` NOT `sunny[key]`. When you write `sunny[key]`, you are telling the interpreter to get the value of the variable `key` at run-time, and then access the member with name equal to the **value** of `key` at the time.

The `key` in `sunny.key` is an **identifier**, the iterator variable of your loop is a **variable**. These are two different entities, and the rules of the language dictate which one you actual mean in each context.

The operator `.` applied to **variable** is a **member accessor**, anything that follows this will always be an **identifier**.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Mr. Geek in comment, sunny.key here in essence is looking for a attribute of sunny called. Key, which is undefined
If things could work this way then code like this could also work ex

```
Var something = { "Foo" : 123 };
Var key = "Foo";
Console.log(something.key)
```

I guess this example can be easily understood. And why that didn't work or rather shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the loop key is a property which holds the each key of Object.

so when you try `sunny.key` it is actually looking for property name `key`.

when you say `sunny[key]` key is extract with the property of object running in loop. so this notation works.

In other words, `sunny.key` is equal to `sunny["key"]`